# Why not use loss value for stopping the training in Siamese Networks?

Tags: deep-learning, siamese-networks

I was building the training pipeline for a siamese network for one-shot learning. Everybody on the internet uses accuracy rather than loss for stopping training. Why use one-shot accuracy over loss value for stopping? Aren't the concepts of overfitting and underfitting relevant here or am I missing something fundamental in one-shot learning?